# UITextField failed when tap a lot buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I got search function in my ios app. I just compare a string, which user typed, and target strings in this way:

```
if (!([name rangeOfString:searchText].location == NSNotFound) || !([description rangeOfString:searchText].location == NSNotFound))
```

[image]

But when i tap more than one button, my application crush in this place.

And sometimes there is this error:

```
 MyApp [2407:6bf7] -[__NSCFSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4f71c0
 MyApp [2407:6bf7] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4f71c0'
```

Any ideas about this 2 errors?

Thnx.

Comment: Probably memory leak & the `UITextField` is autoreleased .

Answer (score 0):

This log shows that you are sending a message to an over-released object. Thus it cannot return values and sending messages to it would crash. You should allow NSZombies in schemes (press edit scheme) Can you post more code? Show where you release, you have a memory leak. As Shivan Raptor also said UITextField is `autoreleased`

If you are or UITextField is autoreleased and you are sending release to it, get rid of the `release`
Scan through your code, also build and analyze to check for memory leaks...

Comment: i set ARC, so i dont need autoreleased. thnx for answer i will think about it and post more code